# Silverlight object not showing - xap downloading but not launching

Tags: silverlight, xap, download

After downloading the xap file the Silverlight object remains empty or does not showing.
I tried refreshing the deployed site binaries and the xap but unsuccessfully.

Does anybody has some idea what is happening.

BTW. I have another SL site in the same domain and in the same application pool that starts without problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly thanks to everyone for the advices. Problem is solved. Unfortunately, I still does not know the exact reason for the error. The problem was caused Plesk control panel of my hosting company that has changed some settings in web.config files when I asked then to switch a web service under a separate application pool. When we restore a backup copy of web.config silverlight page showed again. I'm not sure which is the exact cause of the problem, but this experience could be of help to all who find themselves in a similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

Is your startup object set correctly in project properties? This sort of situation happens if you e.g. move your App class to a different namespace but forget to update the startup object field in settings.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight applications are client side, so application pool of server has no whatsoever relationship to it.

If you get a blank page (you don't even see the loader of Silverlight or you see it and it hangs) this means your Silverlight application has crashed.

Try to debug and find out what is going on. You probably have some reference issues or XAML errors.

See if all the references are copied into the XAP, (rename .xaml file to .zip and open it).

Look at the 'Output' window in Visual Studio during start of the application.

And last but not least, check your html code of your .HTML file, check the name of the XAP file

Check if your server serves .xap files if not you have to add it to the mime types list

Comment: I know the SL applications are client side but if in the same app pool is running a web service that is used by the SL application it can produce the crash of the app pool and consequently the crash of the source SL applicaiton.

Comment: First Silverlight gets loaded and then it calls your webservice, if this was the case it would open a javascript messagebox with error details.

Comment: No. There are no problems in XAP nor in HTML. The same application works perfectly in development environment. I think the problem is in web service that is used by the SL application. I agree with you but there are no messageboxes with error details nor are in the web console.

Comment: Check if your server serves .xap files if not you have to add it to the mime types list

Answer (score 0):

As they are on the same domain, change the site page that is working to point at the faulty XAP. Then you will know if it is a bug in the hosting page or the XAP file.

Also try Silverlight Spy (has free trial period) to see if the Silverlight XAP is valid.

Xaps are just Zip files if you rename them, so you can do some very basic checks manually.

Comment: No. Changing the working site page to the not working generates the same problem on the working page.

Comment: @Patrik: Based on your other comments the SL app is failing after running. To confirm, replace the main XAML start page in App.cs with a temp XAML page that only has text etc and see of that comes up ok.

Answer (score 0):

Normally this happens to me, when I have different event triggers with the same name;

I need to change the name I give to the triggers.